# Using distributed Caching in SharePoint 2010

Tags: cache, object-cache, output-cache, distributedcache

Currently i am using .Net Cache, to store some data but its not distributed so each WFEs maintain a separate version of data, I want distributed caching, what alternative i have in SP 2010 ?

I heard about AppFebric, but i believe its recommended to add a separate server for it which in our case to feasible any other idea ?